# Getting unwanted decimal places in section titles and subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Im getting these unwanted decimals like 7.0 or 4.4.4 where it should be 7 and 4.4 for a subsection. Heres my code related to section numbers:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage {amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{arydshln}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}} %front matter of document 
\title{X-Ray Tube Operation}

\author{CCDP 2100-Z, Cheryl Cundell}

\date{April 5,2018}
\maketitle

\singlespacing
\newpage 
\doublespacing

\newpage   %table of contents 


\tableofcontents

\newpage


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\section*{\centering{Abstract}}

X-ray imaging a fundamental part of modern day medicine \cite{1}. X-ray imaging, also known as radiology, takes advantage of the properties of X-ray radiation to image bones and organs in the human body. The capacity to produce X-ray radiation is fundamental to the practice of radiology. I will be discussing the mechanism of X-Ray production within a component know as a X-ray tube. and why the 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\newpage



\section{List of figures}


\begin{enumerate} %list of figures and tables etc
  \item Figure 1 Relative energies carried by electromagnetic waves.........pg.2
  \item Figure 2 The main components of an X-ray tube........................pg.3
  \item Figure 3 The flow of current in a X-ray production apparatus.........pg.4
  \item Figure 4 The Mechanism of the Focusing Cup.........pg.6
\end{enumerate}

\section{Nomenclature definitions} 
$F$\hspace{2.5cm}       Force acting upon an electron \newline
$q_e$\hspace{2.5cm}         Charge of electron \newline
$q_2$\hspace{2.5cm}         Charge on cathode or anode \newline
$r $\hspace{2.5cm}          Distance between charges \newline
$m$\hspace{2.5cm}           The mass of an object\newline
$a$\hspace{2.5cm}           The acceleration of an object\newline
$a_e$   \hspace{2.5cm}      The acceleration of an electron in a X-ray tube

\section{Abbreviations}
\begin{enumerate} %list of figures and tables etc
  \item \textbf{TE} Thermionic Emission
  \item \textbf{DC} Direct Current

\end{enumerate}
\doublespacing
\newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}  

\section{X-ray use in Hospitals}%intro
\setcounter{section}{1}

Radiology is a common medical imaging technique due to its ability to diagnose sub-dermal abnormalities in the human body\cite{X1}. This ability to obtain internal images of the human body in a non-intrusive fashion makes X-ray scanning, also known as radiology, a fundamental technology in modern healthcare.

\section{Radiology}    %brackground
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

means that every time you want the section number (for example, in the (sub)section title), you also get the current subsection.

This means that `\section{Section Title}` becomes

```
\arabic{section}.0 Section Title
```

(because the subsection counter just reset), while

```
\subsection{Subsection Title}
```

becomes

```
\thesection.\arabic{subsection} Subsection Title
```

which becomes

```
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsection} Subsection Title
```

I'm not sure what you aim to accomplish with that command.  Can you just remove it?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have diagnosed the problem and replaced the code